# HTML Content Security Policy mailto/tel schemes

Tags: html, cordova, content-security-policy

This question is about the HTML meta Content-Security-Policy tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives), a way to describe which resources are accessible from the HTML (styles, scripts, documents, whatever).

I'm having trouble allowing through this tag to allow mailto: and tel: schemes. I tried putting them in almost every directive but it just won't work, trying to access these resources will just fail.

In my case I need it for Cordova apps. In the older versions they had a own whitelisting method that worked, but in the last version they are deprecating this method and are asking people to use this meta tag instead.

Comment: Have you read about `intent whitelist` on cordova's documentation? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#intent-whitelist

Comment: That's interesting... I think yes, this will solve my question. But It's strange that this plugin enforces you to use CSP but then also allows you to use the old whitelisting? This is confusing... If I only use `access origin` tags the plugin will complain I'm missing CSP tags in my HTML as soon as I boot the app. I guess I have to use `allow-intent` in config.xml and CSP in the html?

Comment: Yes you have to include the new content security policy meta tag in your HTML file as of cordova 5 and also to whitelist intents in the config.xml.